# Match files starting with a number and underscore using glob

Tags: python, pathlib

Initially I tried

```
folder_path.glob('[0-9]_*.json')
```

Where folder_path is a pathlib.Path object. But it only works for files that start with a single digit.

after failing to find a proper match pattern, I used an additional condition to verify that what precedes the underscore is a numeric string

```
[ file_path for file_path in folder_path.glob('*_*.json') if file_path.name.split('_')[0].isnumeric() ]
```

but that seems like a workaround that only applies to this case.
Is there a better way to match numbers of any length using glob?

Comment: Unfortunately glob is not as flexible as regex. A workaround might be to write folder_path.glob('[0-9]*_*.json') - so it matches any file that has a numeric first character

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression to match the path:

```
import re

res = [file_path for file_path in folder_path.glob('[0-9]*_*.json') if re.match(r"[0-9]+_.*\.json", str(file_path))]
print(res)
```

**Output** *(example)*

```
[PosixPath('123_abc.json')]
```

Python's glob modules follows the rules used by the Unix shell, from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html):

> The glob module finds all the pathnames matching a specified pattern
> according to the rules used by the Unix shell, although results are
> returned in arbitrary order.

The rules for the Unix shell can be found [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html) these rules  don't include variable pattern length, as in your case.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be supported in python's glob() function. It is more limited than bash. Here is the code for it: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/glob.py

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is fine. When glob patterns don't work, write your own. Glob patterns were invented to make finding files in the shell easier but there is a trade-off between expressiveness and usability. `pathlib` converts your glob to a regular expression and you could too. `pathlib` uses the underlying `os.listdir` and `os.scandir` utilities, but you could stick with `Path.iterdir`

```
import re

my_glob = re.compile(r"\d+_").match
[file_path for file_path in folder_path.iterdir() if my_glob(file_path.name)]
```